# Logstash create more fields from a field regex

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

How do I add new fields from a field in Logstash filter?

example:

```
field1 => '192.168.0.131 abcd 123'
```

final result

```
field1 => '192.168.0.131 abcd 123'
srcip => '192.168.0.131'
word => 'abcd'
number => '123'
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `grok` to parse the results of a previous `grok`, just add another filter into your filter chain.

For example:

```
grok {
  match => { "field1" => "%{IP:srcip} %{WORD:word} %{NUMBER:number} " }
  remove_field => ["field1"]
}
```